# Custom animation iOS

Tags: algorithms, ios, iphone, objective-c, animation

I have seen animation, and i can't figure out how to do something like in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hly8KsEPiok)(youtube). I want to discuss how it's made. I don't think that they're using sprites.

I have one idea how to do this: for example i want to create animation of "walking" animal (when animal moves, he's legs "runs" moving animation), i should create customView with imageView of animalBody [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1mdB.png) and two imageViews of animal legs [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSdey.png). Then i make hard coded animation of moving legs and voila, i have custom animation. When i move customView, then i should start animation of legs. But is there better approach to do this? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question would be stronger if you explained what was occurring in the video and why you don't think sprites are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an IOS expert by far, but if it was me doing this, here's what I'd try to do:

- Decide if you really want to have separate parts of your creature animated separatedly at the code level, or if it suffices to just make 1-animation sprites, each containing the whole creature. Here's what I mean:

  What is this animation part of? Is it part of a game? If so, will the creature in question do multiple kinds of running? Like maybe run and wave his arms, run and throw bananas, etc? If yes, then you may benefit from having a separate set of sprites for the running legs, and a different separate set of sprites for each of the arm-flailing and banana-throwing actions. Then you can combine them to achive full animations

  If on the other hand this guy will only run one way all the time (maybe it's just a cute loading animation), then you'll simplify your code and general project if you make animation sprites each containing the entire creature pose of running animation.
- You'll need a way to pace the animation aka have it run at the same rate/speed on any device, no matter how powerful that device is. Normally, if you want to do it by hand you'd do a game loop. However I'm pretty sure IOS already comes with built in tools for making simple sprite based animations ([like Android does](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)), or (I've just googled this), far more fancier ones like : [Sprite Kit](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Introduction_to_iOS_7_Sprite_Kit_Programming). It's up to you do decide how you'll go about "pacing" your animation. My advice is to first see if you can't already use an existing IOS framework/library, before going into manual coding on this.